# Projection of delimited text file does not match shapefile

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, text

I am using Windows 10 with QGIS 2.10.1 Pisa, and have tried the same on other QGIS versions with the same result.

I am trying to project a delimited text file onto another shapefile, however the two projections will not match whatever I do.

So far I have tried:

- Using a background map (ne_10m_admin_0_countries) with WGS84:EPSG4326
- Background map with WGS84:EPSG3857
- Background map with conic map EPSG:102022
- I have tried saving the text file as a shapefile in each case
- I have also tried all of the above with the openlayers plugin
- I have tried setting the same CRS of the shapefile to the text/shapefile

In all cases, the coordinates move around, but never fit to where they are supposed to. The other shapefile fits beautifully in each situation, and the GPS points I am trying to project have been checked and are correct.

```
Plot_code   Longitude   Latitude    Alt Al-S    As-S    Ba-S    Ca-S    Co-S    Cr-S    Cu-S    Fe-S    Hg-S    K-S Mg-S    Mn-S    Mo-S    Na-S    Nb-S    Ni-S    P-S Pb-S    Rb-S    S-S Sb-S    Se-S    Si-S    Sr-S    Ti-S    U-S V-S Y-S Zn-S    Zr-S
2-1-01-03-CT    0.53237 34.21674    1303.6  67370.08    3.78    375.26  8808.76 7.25    32.07   16.36   18019.95    307.41  48147.05    1832.97 681.62  2.19    7453.65 47.22   14.66   962.82  25.91   391.9   482.89  4.5 2.32    305318.2    143.92  2527.65 17.54   52.98   23.37   122.84  396.83
2-1-01-03-FT    0.53192 34.21778    1295.7  74421.06    4.28    299.04  6073.86 7.85    25.85   16.77   21118.91    2.54    47335.6 491.87  726.28  1.98    7225.7  52.78   18.44   564.39  29.49   417.32  178.11  4.6 2.15    282504.8    116.83  2624.23 19.16   57.39   26.66   78.01   464.67
2-1-01-03-MT    0.53234 34.21722    1300.1  72070.97    5.15    437.69  6356.46 7.63    45.29   12.44   19592.15    NA  51437.09    1187.14 697.89  2.18    7497.35 51.43   16.85   655.4   29.7    425.11  224.67  4.66    2.35    313366.77   113.77  2771.96 21.62   58.22   26.31   72.76   449.88
2-1-01-06-CT    0.53234 34.21628    1302.6  70188.74    3.92    309.57  6229.26 7.71    50.31   15.02   18467.58    NA  54242.03    481.89  477.39  2.12    7445.71 48.51   14.28   518.77  25.58   429.22  236.01  4.77    2.02    308015.37   110.12  2507.86 18.47   56.46   22.39   76.5    397.82
2-1-01-06-MT    0.53244 34.21593    1303.6  75760.14    5.17    420.7   5412.34 8.15    27.1    14.28   21409.93    NA  50840.38    89.47   548.52  1.99    7293.96 47.83   14.89   433.44  34.1    458.1   210.27  4.64    2.7 285652.42   120.56  2666.82 22.17   61.04   26.16   66.54   476.81
2-1-01-08-CT    0.53721 34.21689    1338.8  67282.55    4.39    340.27  5053.28 7.25    31.92   10.71   17658.11    NA  56488.27    1139.49 571.27  1.94    7347.79 52.95   13.45   339.38  28.37   436.39  130.16  4.68    2.36    325334.21   90.64   2617.23 19.46   56.02   24.8    57.74   439.38
2-1-01-08-MT    0.53656 34.21752    1328    63928.37    4.05    435.14  5353.69 6.9 41.04   10.33   15110.59    NA  56868.25    1137.7  544.17  1.99    7379.4  43.2    13.54   334.23  27.41   431.99  137.67  4.6 1.95    346056.7    91.98   2301.29 20.65   50.06   21.07   52.77   397.91
2-1-04-07-CT    0.59156 34.24355    1179.5  6901.13 2.2 436.73  2497.35 5.02    23.46   11.96   5719.69 NA  27490.48    3331.05 141.24  2.43    6654.78 30.8    5.38    NA  13.38   118.87  NA  4.63    1.78    548831.16   77.48   1550.86 4.87    39.25   10.19   28.88   724.74
2-1-04-07-FT    0.59153 34.24282    1179    487.21  2.01    377.85  2351.34 4.62    18.8    4.96    4649.69 NA  28050.41    3265.53 174.52  2.65    6497.28 24.99   6.38    NA  13.71   114.74  NA  4.82    1.31    565137.02   77.02   1477.41 5.33    38.45   13.59   26.12   653.12
2-1-04-07-MT    0.59153 34.24294    1179.1  8996.03 2.18    468.3   2580.06 5.04    24.49   8.77    5977.46 NA  28001.39    3198.4  164.27  2.48    6475.02 30.14   6.96    NA  13.4    117.33  NA  4.87    1.29    540065.51   75.52   1595.78 3.65    37.14   14.87   29.26   723.53
```

Comment: IF the coordinates in the text files are lat/lon then your first option should have worked. The only real question here is which CRS your text file coordinates are in. Can you share the data?

Comment: The data was collected using a Garmin GPS, and then converted from gpx to csv using http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/convert_input

Comment: i'm not sure how to share the data

Comment: Just paste the first ten lines of your CSV in the question. You can remove columns that are not relevant.

Comment: Did you enable the Project (menu)>Project Properties>CRS (tab)>Enable 'on the fly' CRS transformation checkbox?

Comment: How wrong are the locations? By a couple of meters or hundreds of km away or...?

Comment: There's a possibility that the lat/lon values in the table are DD.MMmmm. that is, degrees, decimal minutes like: 34 21.674.If so,  you may have to convert them to decimal degrees before they're usable.

Comment: Yes I have tried activating on the fly, and also without. The locations change depending on the projection. But they are always hundreds of km away. the closest I was was with the EPSG:102022 projection.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem in the conversion of the gpx to csv format, the converter I used (GPS Babel) switched the X and Y coordinates, therefore switching latitude and longitude. The error has been mended and everything fits now. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: You should be able to add the GPX file to QGIS as well, without conversion to a text file.